# How to change index in Laravel Builder Eloquent

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to customize the index of array in Laravel Builder?

I need the index is not incremented from 0 but with some integer

[image]

This is my code:

```
foreach ($members as $member) {
            $check[$member->id] = TransactionInNon::where('member_id', $member->id)
                                                    ->whereYear('created_at', $year)
                                                    ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
                                                    ->limit(12)
                                                    ->get()
                                                    ->toArray();
        }
```

I need the index of array can be customizable like

`7 => array:11`
`10 => array:11`

instead of

`0 => array:11`
`1 => array:11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with mapWithKeys method in laravel collection. For to show result you may change script like this:

```php
#start from
$i = 33;

foreach ($members as $member) {
    $check[$member->id] = TransactionInNon::where('member_id', $member->id)
        ->whereYear('created_at', $year)
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->limit(12)
        ->get()
        ->mapWithKeys(function($item,$key) use (&$i) {
            $i++;
            return  [$i => $item];
        })
        ->toArray();
      # if you want to set $i like old content
      $i = 33;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works fine.
But Is it possible to loop the builder by any chance? Currently the array size is determine by the amount of data, Is it possible to set the array index size?

Comment: Yes of course , you can set zero at the end every loop action. I will change my script

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because PHP array index starts from 0